# Dovecot LDA to deliver to 2 servers at once

Tags: sync, rsync, dovecot, exim

I'd like to build robust mail system that can withstand outages. For this purpose I rent 2 servers (lets call it `mx1` and `mx2`) in 2 different datacenters, set up Exim on both as SMTP, and Dovecot as LDA, IMAP and POP3 server (Exim pass the message to Dovecot LDA to deliver it).

Now I'd like to sync mail storages of these servers so even if one of these servers will disappear I'll simple change DNS for, say, `mx1` to have it point to `mx2` address, and all the same mailstore be available to serve messages from.

The problem is, I don't like to rsync whole mailstorage from `mx1` to `mx2` and vise versa to keep mailstorages synced (it takes a lot of resources to find out only a few messages to copy over; and to keep storages as synced as I can afford I'll have to set up cron this rsync at, say, each 5 minutes).

At the same time, I think once I saw some config for Exim or Dovecot LDA so LDA will deliver the same message to both servers. So now, **please advice on how should I set up robust mail system so my users stay happy, and the solution be nice and good-engineered** ) So to say, it is not necessary to use Dovecot as LDA as Exim can deliver inself, I just wanted to know how to withstand one of mx-es outage, or whole DC (one of two DCs) offline or outage.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I voted to close as this is a massive topic with no single good solution, and lots if technology options.  Its not amenable to a superuser post (wete it not so vague it might belong on serverfault.com)

Comment: rsync is not s great tool as its not real-time. You could look at a distributed disk solution like gluster, or drbd or others, or a distributed database backend. Of-course  devil is in the details  with issues like resolving split brain and how to provide a unified frontend to clients.  Its often easier to build a single robust cluster and use multiple carriers to get to the same hardware.  Larger scale deployments may involve sharding your users or eventual consistency models depending on your criteria.

Comment: A possibility might be a master-slave config, ie always send email to master which replicates to slave  switching to slave if master is unavailable. Still have to deal with split brain (but its easier) and you smtp volume reputation/volume issues on slave, but master slave replication on drbd or mars may be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider setting up Dovecot with replication, see: https://wiki.dovecot.org/Replication